# Disabling a compromised user account

Tags: unix, security

I have a simple question for you, well, at least, much simpler than "How do I clean up a compromised user account?"  The question is: "How do I disable a compromised user account?" There are some obvious things to do:

- Disable logins for the user (we've done this by changing their home directory to /disabled/home/user)
- Disable the users Apache websites (once again, but replacing with bogus paths.)
- Killing off all the users processes using `pkill -9 -u username`
- Checking they have no spooled cronjobs

So, if their processes mysteriously come *back* after doing these things, what did we miss?

Answer (score 5):

I'd also do the following:

```
 a. Disable the account password, via passwd -l
 b. Change the users' login shell to /bin/false
 c. Remove the users' .ssh directory
 d. Remove the users' .rhosts file
```

Comment: We don't have account passwords! (We use Kerberos, and don't have control of the realm.) If the users home directory was changed, does that make .ssh and .rhosts moot?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mdpc on this. I might add another suggestion, though, in addition to his recommendations. There is a method of putting limits on user processes, per user, via /etc/security/limits.conf. (I don't know if this is uniform across all distributions.) You may be able to disallow processes belonging to that user by setting the limit to 0.

[This link](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml) might help you - see section 1.4 on Limits.